# How can I use nested quotes when calling a PowerShell script within a VBScript file?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm a VBScript and PowerShell newbie. I have a PowerShell script that runs correctly when I call it from the command line. However when I try and call it from VBScript, it runs but does nothing.

The command I use on the CLI that works is

```
powershell.exe -nop -exec bypass -noni -command "& { . C:\<censored path>\testscript1.ps1; Get-Test }"
```

This works. When I run the following vbscript code, I get no results

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.run("powershell.exe -nop -exec bypass -noni -command &""& { . C:\<censored path>\testscript1.ps1; Get-Test }" &"")
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: After trimming down my command to:

```
objShell.run("powershell.exe -nop -exec bypass -noni -command "& { . C:\<censored path>\testscript1.ps1; Get-Test }" ")
```

I get a Code 800A0408 - Invalid Character error for the opening brace bracket. I have tried escaping both brackets, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
PSCommand = "powershell.exe -nop -exec bypass -noni -command" & DblQuote("& { . C:\<censored path>\testscript1.ps1; Get-Test }")&""
MsgBox PSCommand 
set objShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
objShell.Run PSCommand
'****************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'****************************************************************
```